# Horizontal ScrollBar Disappears when Console Window is Resized

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I have a simple Console Application and the horizontal ScrollBar disappears when I resize the window. However, the vertical ScrollBar remains visible. Is there a way to fix this problem. I'm using the following console settings in my `main`.

```
if (Environment.UserInteractive)
{
    // Console dimensions 
    Console.SetWindowSize(80, 20);
    Console.BufferWidth = 120;
    Console.BufferHeight = Int16.MaxValue - 1;

    var service = new WindowsService();
    service.ManualStartAndStop(args);
}
else
{
    ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
    ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
    {
    new WindowsService()
    {
        ServiceName = "TestService"
    }
    };
    ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
}
```

Edited: The problem was, the text wrapping property was enabled, so when the console window was resized the text would wrap and the Horizontal scrollbar would disappear. Disabling the text wrapping property resolved the problem.

Comment: Which is the problem; that the horizontal bar disappears or that the vertical remains?

Comment: What did you set the console BufferWidth to?

Answer (score 0):

If you want no scroll bars, set the buffer width and height to the same as the window sizes. If you want scrollbars, set the buffer width and height to larger than the window size. If the buffer is wider than the window you will get a horizontal scroll bar. If the buffer is taller than the window you will get a vertical scroll bar. If the user resizes the window to as-large/larger then the relevant buffer dimension the scroll bar disappears

To play more with buffer and window sizes (to further your understanding) open a command prompt window and right click the title bar/get properties. Buffer is the size and f the thing that holds the text, window is the size of the viewport onto that data

Comment: Thanks for the information. But no matter what I set the WindowSize to, as soon as the console is resized w/ text in it, the Horizontal scrollbar disappears and the text goes into wrapped mode. I think I need to disable the text wrapping and that will fix it since I can set that in the properties. Is there a way to programmatically disable text wrapping?

Comment: You still haven't really said what the problem is. If your buffer is set to 160 wide and the window 80 wide and you print out 100 chars there will be 20 chars not visible, not wrapped. If you print out 200 chars there will be 80 chars visible, then 80 not visible on the same line, then 40 chars wrapped(visible). If the user resizes the window to 160 wide all chars become visible and the hscrollbar disappears